# Unable to Fetch data through web service in Android 10 / API 29

Tags: android, soap

I am using Soap class to fetch data from database through web service, it working fine with code given:

```
        public String Call() {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
        Object response = null;
        try {
           httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
           response = envelope.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            response = exception.toString();
        }
        return response.toString();
    }
```

this code working fine till API 28 / Android 9 but same code stop working
in API 29/Android 10 as my client update  from Android 9 to Android 10. all my clients have update android 10 unable to connect now while till Android 9 this is working correctly. i also install the SSL on my web service site. but still unable to fetch data.
application just crash without giving any exception on

httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

in API 29

Answer (score 0):

I have done, as i was using

**ksoap2-android-2.5.2.jar**

in my application, i just replace it with

**ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar**

It is working now